Payload CMS + Lexical Editor: image block insertion into lexical editor
I have a quite complex task - I need to migrate content from another CMS into Payload 3.0. Content: posts, works, articles with rich texts, assets...
packages:

payloadcms: 3.0.0-beta.20
lexical: 0.14.5

These are the features that I use in my Lexical Editor:
const features = [
   HeadingFeature({ enabledHeadingSizes: ['h2', 'h3'] }),
   ParagraphFeature(),
   ItalicFeature(),
   BoldFeature(),
   OrderedListFeature(),
   UnorderedListFeature(),
   LinkFeature({ enabledCollections: [] }),
   BlocksFeature({
   blocks: [
    {
     slug: 'image',
     interfaceName: 'Image',
     fields: [
      {
       name: 'image',
       type: 'upload',
       relationTo: 'images',
       required: true,
      },
     ],
    },
   ],
  }),
],

This is the example content field of type richText from one of my Payload CMS collections (Post, Work, Article):
{
   name: 'content',
   type: 'richText',
   required: true,
   editor: lexicalEditor({
     features: ({}) => features
   }),
 },

Headless Lexical editor creation with the same features
const headlessEditor = createHeadlessEditor({
    nodes: getEnabledNodes({
      editorConfig: sanitizeServerEditorConfig({
        features
      }),
    }),
  });

...
const rawData = await fs.promises.readFile('./src/data/articles.json');
const data= JSON.parse(rawData.toString());
...

Using update method from headless editor I'm inserting nodes generated from HTML which I get from JSON.
headlessEditor.update(
   () => {
      const root = $getRoot();
      const dom = new JSDOM(HTMLValue);
      const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(headlessEditor, dom.window.document);
      root.select();
      const selection = $getSelection();
      selection?.insertNodes(nodes);
  },
  { discrete: true },
);

Question: How to create image block which inside itself contains image and insert it into the headless editor as well ?
const createdImage = await payload.create({
    collection: 'images',
    data: {
      originalUrl: assetData.url,
    },
    filePath,
  });

  headlessEditor.update(
    () => {
      $getRoot().append(
        /** How to ? */
      );
    },
    { discrete: true },
  );

Tried to use $createBlockNode but didn't find out how to correctly exploit it. Also I didn't find any guidance in Lexical documentation regarding this.

Did you find a solution?
